# Keeping viewport at same hight

Tags: html, css, zooming, viewport, pixel

I want a page with a fixed pixel size to always have the same percantage hight. I cant just use % or any other relative units since I already made the whole site in pixels.

Means when I have a div with a hight of 1500px and view it on a 1366x768 screen the whole 1500px div should still be visable completely.

The effect I want to accomplish is something similar to a browser zoom.

Comment: Have you tried using viewport units?

Answer (score 0):

You could try `min-height: 1500px;` on the div, then put `overflow-y: auto` on the body or html elements.

If you want something to dynamically resize depending on the window height you'll want to look into either CSS flexbox, using the vh sizing, or using javascript to detect window resizing.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) for that. Just remove the "initial-scale=1" part and the page should always be rendered to fit the screen.

You should note that this might result in the page being shown very small which can lead to problems when people want to access it with a smartphone for example. If you want to optimize your page for different devices and screens, I suggest you make yourself familiar with [responsive webdesign](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web_Development/Mobile/Responsive_design).

Something like height: 100vh; would make the object's height 100 percent of the viewport height. It seems like there is no way around switching from px to something else.

Comment: I tryed it and nothing changed. Keeping viewport at same hight.

Comment: maybe this helps. https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRDK5.png 
this is how the page looks like with a small screen.

Comment: Have you tried setting the height to "device-height"?

Comment: It would have been a bad solution anyway. You could use what others already suggested: viewport units.

Comment: well the problem on my site is that the width has to stay in same proportion to the height. 

http://palmira-lopez.de/

If I would want to do it with viewport units I would have to size every single container and rezize the font